# How I get minimize window active side?

Tags: system, release-juno, elementary-project, minimize

I am so long time (like 1 years) using elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki for this I love here a settings (ACTIVE SIDE! MINIMIZE ACTIVE WINDOW OPTION!!) I loving this, but elementary OS 5.0 Juno don't have this can I get this settings in 5.0 Juno else I am installing now 0.4.1 Loki?

Comment: ctrl + H (or click the icon in dock)

Comment: sorry it's Super+H :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

Then open settings and change that option in Tweaks menu.

Comment: Thank you, I installed now 0.4.1 Loki a while later I upgrade my elementary.

Answer (score 1):

With Elementary OS's Juno release, this option is conveniently placed in the System Settings.

**Navigation: Setting -> Desktop -> Dock**

Once at this location, the Dock behaviour controls are Icon Size, **Hide When** and Pressure Reveal. The **Hide When** control also has a toggle. If the toggle is set to **OFF**, the dock stays locked in its position.

[image]
[image]